# scrolling/sliding background in html5 canvas

Tags: html, canvas, background

I am building a canvas game. In this i want to slide the background image in a loop. I don't know how to do this using javascript. I will be using single image which will slide continuously into the background.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure you could continuously slide one image - you could slide two halves which join seamlessly at the edges.

Comment: @Coulton theres no reason to use jQuery it does nothing with canvas.

Comment: @Widor You can most definitely use one image, you just copy portions of it to the canvas creating the seamless effect.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Theres a few ways to achieve this the first one will take a performance hit using `putImageData`, the second method just uses `drawImage`. Also note the 2nd method has the code to make it go either from left to right, or right to left.

http://www.somethinghitme.com/projects/bgscroll/

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d"),
    canvasTemp = document.createElement("canvas"),
    scrollImg = new Image(),
    tempContext = canvasTemp.getContext("2d"),
    imgWidth = 0,
    imgHeight =0,
    imageData = {},
    canvasWidth = 600,
    canvasHeight = 240,
    scrollVal = 0,
    speed =2;

    scrollImg.src = "citybg.png";
    scrollImg.onload = loadImage;

    function loadImage(){
        imgWidth = scrollImg.width,
        imgHeight = scrollImg.height;
        canvasTemp.width = imgWidth;
        canvasTemp.height =  imgHeight;    
        tempContext.drawImage(scrollImg, 0,0, imgWidth, imgHeight); 
        imageData = tempContext.getImageData(0,0,imgWidth,imgHeight);
        render();                
    }

    function render(){
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvasWidth,canvasHeight);

        if(scrollVal >= canvasWidth-speed){
            scrollVal = 0;
        }

        scrollVal+=speed;

        // This is the bread and butter, you have to make sure the imagedata isnt larger than the canvas your putting image data to.
        imageData = tempContext.getImageData(canvasWidth-scrollVal,0,scrollVal,canvasHeight);
        ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0,0,0,0,scrollVal, imgHeight);
        imageData = tempContext.getImageData(0,0,canvasWidth-scrollVal,canvasHeight);
        ctx.putImageData(imageData, scrollVal,0,0,0,canvasWidth-scrollVal, imgHeight);

        setTimeout(function(){render();},10);
    }
```

**2nd Method** uses the same code as above, just change these two functions to the following.

http://www.somethinghitme.com/projects/bgscroll/scrolldrawimage.html

```
function loadImage(){
    imgWidth = scrollImg.width,
    imgHeight = scrollImg.height;
    canvasTemp.width = imgWidth;
    canvasTemp.height =  imgHeight;    
    render();                
}

function render(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvasWidth,canvasHeight);

    if(scrollVal >= canvasWidth){
        scrollVal = 0;
    }

    scrollVal+=speed;                   
    ctx.drawImage(scrollImg,canvasWidth-scrollVal,0,scrollVal,imgHeight, 0, 0, scrollVal,imgHeight);
    ctx.drawImage(scrollImg,scrollVal,0,imgWidth, imgHeight);

     // To go the other way instead
     ctx.drawImage(scrollImg,-scrollVal,0,imgWidth, imgHeight);
     ctx.drawImage(scrollImg,canvasWidth-scrollVal,0,imgWidth, imgHeight);

    setTimeout(function(){render();},10);
}
```

Comment: Hi Loktar, thanks for the answer. Could you please tell me how to reverse the direction (from right to left). I tried it but no success.

Comment: @user1451031 I edited my answer and added it to the second method under the comment `//To go the other way` since the 2nd method is the one that performs better.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I try to use the 2nd method and the reverse block ("right to left").  The problem I have is that I need to position my images but if I add the 6th,7th,8th and 9th parameters to [drawImage](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_drawimage.asp), it reverses and goes left to right again. Very,very weird.  An idea about it ?

Comment: About my previous comment, I finally managed to do it : http://stackoverflow.com/a/29731069/782013